# Why does my countdown function run to quickly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, countdowntimer

I have a countdown function in vue.js that updates too fast.

Here is the data section

```
data() {
        return {
            selected: [],
            countdown: timerLimit
        }
```

Below is the countdown method

```
countdownTimer() {
        this.countdown = 60;
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(() => {
            if(this.countdown <= 0){
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                if (this.thisUser.captain) {
                        Store.submitTurnEnd();
                    }
            }
            this.countdown -= 1
            console.log(this.countdown)
            }, 1000);
        },
```

Which gets called above. However, I notice after clicking a few times, it often goes too fast. I think I need to update the data section but am unsure how to.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could help you whit another variable in data:

```
data() {
        return {
            selected: [],
            countdown: timerLimit,
            isCountdownActive: false
}
```

Method:

```
countdownTimer() {
        // exit method if it is active
        if(this.isCountdownActive == true) return;

        // first time set ttrue
        this.isCountdownActive = true

        this.countdown = 60;
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(() => {
            if(this.countdown <= 0){
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                if (this.thisUser.captain) {
                        Store.submitTurnEnd();
                }

                // On exit interval, restart to false 
                this.isCountdownActive = false
            }
            this.countdown -= 1
            console.log(this.countdown)
            }, 1000);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 5
  },
  methods: {
    countdownTimer: function() {
        let interval;

        interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.counter > 0) {
                this.counter = this.counter - 1;
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
                // Do whatever you want to do
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
  }
})
```

And the template part is

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Countdown:</h2>
  <h1>{{ counter }}</h1>
  <button v-on:click="countdownTimer">Start</button>
</div>
```